# Keystone, show blog category on index page

Tags: javascript, pug, keystonejs

I am new to keystone and need a little javascript help. I am trying to show all of the posts with a specific category on my home page (index). Could someone help me out with it? Point me in a direction to look or explain how to make this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this keystone demo, it's simple and helps a lot at the beginning: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-demo